# Automaticlly attach to pivot table in Laravel 5

Tags: php, eloquent, pivot, relational-database, laravel-5

I currently have a Users to Groups Relationship (ManyToMany) with a pivot table group_user. I want the user to be able to create a group but once creating the group, how do I make it, that the creator becomes member of this group?

Currently I have

My Pivot Table (group_user):

```
Schema::create('group_user', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

My Groups table (groups):

```
Schema::create('groups', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

My Users table (users):

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

My models ofcourse have the following: User.php

```
public function groups() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
    }
```

Group.php

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

What create function should I write in my controller so that when a User creates a Group, that he automaticly becomes member of this group (automaticlly make the pivot relationship)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, make sure you implement validation, ect.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $group = Group::create([ // <-- if names are unique. if not, then create is fine
        'name' => $request->get('name')
        ]);
        auth()->user()->groups()->attach([$group->id]);

        return view('your.view');

    }
```

Also make sure to add:

```
use App\Group;
```

Comment: Hmm I seem to be getting one small error. My POST seems to be going to the wrong 'action url'
This is my form: {!! Form::model(['route' => ['group.store'], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
These are my routes in routes.php: $router->post('groups', ['as' => 'group.store', 'uses' => 'GroupController@store']);
    $router->get('group/create', ['as' => 'group.create', 'uses' => 'GroupController@create']);
The acount I seem to be getting is: action="http://project.dev:8000/group/create"

Comment: Try this: {!! Form::open(['route' => 'group.store']) !!}

Answer (score 1):

See attach() and detach().

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->groups()->attach(10); // pivot relationship of this user to group of id 1.
```

OR

```
$group = Group::find(10);
$user->groups()->save($group);
```

For many groups of this user:

```
$user->groups()->sync(array(1, 2, 3));
```